# Perl threads: auto restart in case of error or out

Tags: multithreading, perl, loops

There is an infinite loop, about as below. And the function "new_task" can give an error because of which the thread will die or pause (I do not know).
**Is it possible to automatically restart the stream in this case?**
I did not find an answer on the Internet, or I did not understand. Thank you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub new_task {
    print "Hello! I may be die..";
}

sub threaded_task {
    threads->create(\&new_task,);
}

while (1) {
    threaded_task();
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Exceptions can be caught using `eval BLOCK`.

Comment: ikegami, Is it possible to set an example?

Comment: ["Catching Exceptions" in *Modern Perl*](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/08-perl-style-efficiency.html#Q2F0Y2hpbmdFeGNlcHRpb25z), [perldoc -f eval](http://p3rl.org/eval)

Comment: In you sample code, I don't see anything that would cause a thread to "die or pause" and don't see anything related streams.  I may be wrong, but it kind of feels like this might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  You've highlighted your question about restarting streams, but the question title is about threads.  That sounds like you have a problem with interacting with a stream (Y), but you're asking for help about threads (X).

Comment: If a thread does die, there's probably something wrong with the data or the logic, so simply repeating would create a never-ending loop of error messages.  If there's really some kind of other issue, like service unavailable, then you need to check if it's available and catch that exception and push the uncompleted task to the end of your queue (or block and wait for the resources to be available so the task can finish).

Comment: In the streams, the JSON data is disassembled. And sometimes the web server sends a "500" error, for example. And because of this, the JSON kills the stream.

Comment: I test used "Try::Tiny" and "try - catch" and operator "next" in the function JSON parsing. It seems to work so far ..